# label-image orientation in c# windowsphone componentone maps

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, maps, componentone

I am using componentone (C1) maps for a project in c# for windowsphone-8. I added a car image as a label in a given point and I would like to change its orientation (if the car goes north, I should move the car face north, etc.) (-not only N-S-E-V, but  NE or a 73 degree angle).

I used a vector placemark and I gave its label an image. I couldn't find in its proprieties anything that might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i ve managed to do it . the idea: when label gets the image,image has a rendertransform proriety who gets New RotateTransform that has an Angle propriety.